# Are service callbacks queued?

Tags: ros, callback, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

Reading the doc and tutorials I understand that when the topics are received (on the subscriber side) they are queued in a callback queue before being processed (on a call to spin(), spinOnce(), callAvailable(), callOne()...). Now what I did not get is weather the service callbacks (on the server side) were also queued in the same callback queue. Hence the question:

Are the service callbacks queued in the same callback queue than the topics or are they processed independently as soon as they are received (i.e. without waiting for a spin(), spinOnce(), callAvailable(), callOne()...))?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195137/are-service-callbacks-queued?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-10-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, yes they are all queued on the node's callback queue.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-10-16**:
Simple and clear, thanks!